# javascript timer minus counting

Tags: javascript

Hello i want when the timer reaches the deadline to stop counting... and it stops, but when i make a refresh its counting in minus like this http://prntscr.com/9m17mn

i want when it reach 0 to stay like that and after refresh

thanks in advance

heres the code

```js
<script>
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = "2016-01-04T18:04:00.000+01:00";
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);


</script>
```

Comment: Where's your refresh code?

Comment: why can't you try ready-made jquery plugin

Comment: When I try to create a demo, it looks like it works for me flawlessly in chrome **unless** I switch tabs before it ends.   Then it displays the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/egm6voey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are checking to see if the timer should be stopped after setting the html which means that you would potentially show negative values:

```
function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      daysSpan.innerHTML = '0';
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = '0';
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = '0';
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = '0';
    } else {
      daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```js
<script>
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    
    daysSpan.innerHTML = (t.total>0)?t.days:"0";
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = (t.hours>0)?('0' + t.hours).slice(-2):"00";
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = (t.minutes>0)?('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2):"00";
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = (t.seconds>0)?('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2):"00";

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = "2016-01-04T18:04:00.000+01:00";
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);


</script>
```